# How can I manually put a packet to the Head of TX queue?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel-module, nic

As far as I know, in order to send an packet, network driver will modify the TDT (transmit descriptor tail) to point to that packet and the NIC will read from the TDH (transmit descriptor head), send packet and modify this TDH.

What I want is to put a packet to head of TX queue. Is it achievable? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you would have to heavily patch you NIC's driver to do this.

But prioritization could be easily achived with prio qdisc in linux (`tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio`). Just mark your high-priority packets with appropriate TOS/DSCP markers and put'em to `flowid 1:1` with `tc filter`.